# .htaccess subdomain redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain, url-rewriting

My server is somehow configured to accept any string as a existing subdomian. This subdomains doesn't redirect, they show content instead. For example:

**bla.example.com** // shows the content of http://example.com

**blabla.example.com** // show the content of http://example.com

**lorem.example.com/events/** // shows the content of http://example.com/events

So you can use "stackoverflow.example.com" and it will work.

I want to create an **.htaccess rule to overwrite this behavior**. I want to redirect http://*.example.com/* to http://www.example.com/*

Everything I have done so far is redirect http://example.com to http://www.example.com (wich is another behavior I want to keep)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following to your htaccess file in the root folder of your domain

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#if its not www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
#redirect it to www.example.com
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```